#  long click to make image visible in gridview

Tags: android, gridview, android-widget

I have 2 images in each cell of gridview. First image is invisible and second image is visible. what i want is when i use long click any item of gridview the invisible image should be visible.Thank you.

```
myGrid.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {
            DELETE_SIT=1;

            //Toast.makeText(FavorilerAct.this,"long click"+DELETE_SIT, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ((BaseAdapter)myGrid.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

            return true;
        }
    });
```

// And this is my getview  method in custom adapter extend BaseAdapter

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
       {
          View MyView = convertView;
          String url = stock_list.get(position);

      if ( convertView == null )
      {
         LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
         MyView = li.inflate(R.layout.gridview, null);

         // Add The Text!!!
         TextView tv = (TextView)MyView.findViewById(R.id.favorite_author);
         tv.setText(names.get(position));
         ImageView img=(ImageView)MyView.findViewById(R.id.favorite_image);
         ImageView artiImg=(ImageView)MyView.findViewById(R.id.delete_fav_btn);
         if(DELETE_SIT!=1)
             artiImg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
         else
             artiImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        try {
            img.setImageBitmap(loadBitmap(url));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(DELETE_SIT==1){
            //ImageView delete_btn=(ImageView)MyView.findViewById(R.id.delete_fav_btn);
            //artiImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.kapat);
            artiImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
      }

      return MyView;
   }
```

Comment: And what's your problem?

Comment: when i use long click for gridview, second image which was invisible is not being visible.

Comment: ok let me insert my code

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just try smthing this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
      View vi= convertView;
      String url = stock_list.get(position);
      ViewHolder holder = null;

      if ( vi == null )
      {
          LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
          vi = li.inflate(R.layout.gridview, null);
          holder = new ViewHolder();

          holder.tv = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.favorite_author);
          holder.img=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.favorite_image);
          holder.artiImg=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.delete_fav_btn);

          vi.setTag(holder);
       }else{
           holder = (ViewHolder)vi.getTag();
       }

       holder.tv.setText(names.get(position));

      if(DELETE_SIT!=1){
          try {
              holder.img.setImageBitmap(loadBitmap(url));
          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          holder.img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          holder.artiImg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
      }
      else{
          holder.img.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
          holder.artiImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }

   }

  return vi;
}

static class ViewHolder{
    public TextView tv;
    public ImageView img;
    public ImageView artiImg;
}
```

Let me know if you still have problems.

Comment: i could not understand why i need to know the state of each cell. I just need to long click on any cell and then all cell will have a second image.

Comment: @Emilla Oh ok, sry, I didn't get it! I will edit my post when I have time

Comment: @Emilla Why don't you change the visibility of your ImageView "img" anywhere ?

Comment: No .. it is not possible.. As you can see from my code i just need to set something which can warn getview method to make second images visible...maybe we can just suppose we have 2 getview method when long click on any item of gridview one of these 2 getview method will run. Maybe first getview will have visible images and second one will have invisible images